# shouldReceiveTouch not called

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I see a lot of question about it on web, and particularly on StackOverflow.
I test many given answers but in my case, nothing works.

My class implements the protocol `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
@interface CDMapViewController : CDViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

The following method is wrote from xcode autocompletion in @implentation of my class

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"not called");
    return NO;
}
```

I have correctly init the UIGestureRecognizer in first method which correctly call the second, third and fourth methods:

```
- (void)initGestureOnMap {
    UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    gesture_dragging = NO;
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    gesture_dragging = YES;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if (gesture_dragging || [touches count] != 1) return;
        /* bla bla bla */
}
```

... It doesn't log – not called ... why ?

Comment: Gesture recognizers were meant to replace `touchesBegan:` and all those methods. You typically only need to implement one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `super` implementations for the `touches` methods.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    gesture_dragging = NO;
}

... and so on.
```

These methods need to be implemented on your *view*, and not your view controller.

Pick what kind of gesture you want. By itself, `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't do much, so pick one like `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Next, implement your gesture recognizer with the designated initializer.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)];
```

Finally, implement `myMethod:`.

```
-(void)myMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // Whatever this does.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I do this now ... But it doesn't solve the problem. It doesn't call theshouldReceiveTouch function

Comment: What kind of gesture are you looking for? A tap? You need to use a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to catch a tap, but it is on MKMapView to select overlay.
And I'd like to call shouldReceiveTouch to disable the touch on an info bar on top of mapView.

Comment: I've edited the answer – you need to create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead.

Comment: Yes, I try this, but I'd like to avoid using selector because the "UItouch" is not pass in parameter .. But, obviously, I have no choice ...
I check the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help ... I choice to keep touchesBegan method